# Is there a way to use leaflet.heat in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, leaflet

I am trying to use **leaflet.heat in reactJS**. I have already made leaflet library to work with react hooks but unfortunately I can't use leaflet.heat in react. I import the module like:

```
import "../libraries/HeatLayer";
```

And the code for HeatLayer.js is:
https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.heat/blob/gh-pages/src/HeatLayer.js

When I run the react app I do not get any errors but the leaflet heatmap is not displayed

NOTE: I don't want to use components such as react-leaflet nor react-leaflet-heatmap.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- install `leaflet.heat` via npm : `npm i leaflet.heat`
- import the library: `import "leaflet.heat";`
- Create a map component and use an effect to load the map and instantiate `L.heatLayer`

Here is an example from the library's github page written in React without react-leaflet components:

```
function Map() {
  useEffect(() => {
    var map = L.map("map").setView([-37.87, 175.475], 12);

    L.tileLayer("https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png", {
      attribution:
        '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
    }).addTo(map);

    const points = addressPoints
      ? addressPoints.map((p) => {
          return [p[0], p[1]];
        })
      : [];

    L.heatLayer(points).addTo(map);
  }, []);

  return <div id="map" style={{ height: "100vh" }}></div>;
}
```

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/how-to-use-leafletheat-in-react-without-react-leaflet-components-5s76z?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: thank you very much!!! Sorry for not givingg feedback, not enougth reputation

Comment: So I'm looking at the address points (e.g. `[-37.8839, 175.3745188667, "571"]`). Is the format `[lat, lng, weight]`?

Answer (score 3):

For React Leaflet V3 useMap hook makes it really easy too:

```
import { useMap } from 'react-leaflet'
import L from 'leaflet'
import "leaflet.heat"
function heatmapFunction(){
   const map = useMap()
   useEffect(() => {
     const points = addressPoints
     ? addressPoints.map((p) => {
       return [p[0], p[1], p[2]]; // lat lng intensity
       })
     : [];

     L.heatLayer(points).addTo(map);
   }, []);
}
```

This way you can break the heat map into it's own component etc.