# Why don't heatmap colors appear on the map?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, leaflet, react-leaflet

I want to ask i.e. Why is the heatmap color not showing on the map? and I use from API and GeoJSON is there anything wrong with my own coding? Is there any part of `const position = response.features`? [Link 1](https://codesandbox.io/s/how-to-use-leaflet-heat-in-react-without-react-leaflet-components-forked-7oj52g?file=/src/Map.jsx:635-641) and [Link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63640081/is-there-a-way-to-use-leaflet-heat-in-react)  
The following example does not show the heatmap color but it comes out like a box and it says `marker`.
[image]

```
useEffect(() => {
            setIsLoading(true);
            getLocation(body)
                .then((response) => {
                    const array = [];
                    response.features.forEach((element) => {
                        array.push({
                            type: "Feature",
                            properties: element["attributes"],
                            geometry: {
                                type: "Point",
                                coordinates: [
                                    element["geometry"]["x"],
                                    element["geometry"]["y"],
                                ],
                            },
                        });
                    });

                    const FeatureCollection = {
                        type: "FeatureCollection",
                        features: array,
                    };
                    if (geoJsonLayer.current) {
                        geoJsonLayer.current.clearLayers().addData(FeatureCollection);
                    }

                    const position = response.features
                        ? response.features.forEach((element) => {
                            return [element["geometry"]["x"], element["geometry"]["y"]];
                        })
                        : [];

                    if (position) {
                        L.heatLayer(position).addTo(FeatureCollection);
                    }

                    setData(FeatureCollection);


                })
                .catch((err) => console.log(err))
                .finally(() => setIsLoading(false));
        };

        fetchData();
    }, [bounds, setIsLoading, tokenArcgis]);
```

your response from getLocation in the example:

```
export const getLocation = async (params) => {
  try {
    const body = DataCustom(params);
    const result = await instanceArcgis.post(
      "/rest/services/HomeLocation/4/query",
      body,
    );
    return await result?.data;
  }
```

Comment: you need to include your response from getLocation in the example to be able to reproduce this otherwise we can  just make assumptions.

Comment: And have added getLocation in the example

Comment: What I mean by response is the actual data you receive. The value of the variable response

Comment: I did not find the actual data you received

Comment: response.features

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does the HeatMap color not appear but the marker text appears?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72934620/why-does-the-heatmap-color-not-appear-but-the-marker-text-appears)