# "TypeError: map.addLayer is not a function"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet

I was copying code from this solution: [Is there a way to use leaflet.heat in react?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63640081/is-there-a-way-to-use-leaflet-heat-in-react) and I'm getting an error

```
TypeError: map.addLayer is not a function
```

[image] 
in the currentPosition function

```
export const currentPosition = atom({
  key: "currentPosition",
  default: [-2.600, -11.01],
});
```

in the getLocationCity function

```
export const getLocationCity = async (params) => {
  try {
    const body = DataCustom(params);
    const result = await instanceArcgis.post(
      "/rest/HomeLocation/11/query",
      body,
    );
    return await result?.data;
  }catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
```

I'm sure it's a var or placement order issue, but I tried various options and it still doesn't work. And it outputs results from the API but no Heatmap color comes out just 'Marker'
[image] 
Full JS code:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, useRef } from "react";
import { GeoJSON } from "react-leaflet";
import { useRecoilValue, useSetRecoilState } from "recoil";
import HeatmapOverlay from "leaflet-heatmap";
import { arcgisToken } from "../recoil";
import { mapBounds, loadingMap } from "../state";
import { getLocationCity } from "../data/arcgis";
import "leaflet.heat";

export default function HSales() {
    const [data, setData] = useState();
    const setIsLoading = useSetRecoilState(loadingMap);
    const bounds = useRecoilValue(mapBounds);
    const tokenArcgis = useRecoilValue(arcgisToken);
    const geoJsonLayer = useRef(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchDataSpeedtestKel = () => {
            const body = {
                returnGeometry: true,
                rollbackOnFailure: true,
                geometry: JSON.stringify({
                    xmin: bounds.west,
                    ymin: bounds.south,
                    xmax: bounds.east,
                    ymax: bounds.north,
                    spatialReference: { wkid: 4326 },
                }),
                geometryType: "esriGeometryEnvelope",
                token: tokenArcgis,
            };

            setIsLoading(true);
            getLocationCity(body)
                .then((response) => {
                    const array = [];
                    response.features.forEach((element) => {
                        array.push({
                            type: "Feature",
                            properties: element["attributes"],
                            geometry: {
                                type: "Point",
                                coordinates: [
                                    element["geometry"]["x"],
                                    element["geometry"]["y"],
                                ],
                            },
                        });
                    });

                    const FeatureCollection = {
                        type: "FeatureCollection",
                        features: array,
                    };

                    if (geoJsonLayer.current) {
                        geoJsonLayer.current.clearLayers().addData(FeatureCollection);
                    }

                    const points = response.features
                        ? response.features.map((element) => {
                            return [
                                element["geometry"]["x"],
                                element["geometry"]["y"]
                            ];
                        })
                        : [];

                    setData(FeatureCollection);
                    L.heatLayer(points).addTo(position);
                    setPosition(data);
                })
                .catch((err) => console.log(err))
                .finally(() => setIsLoading(false));
        };

        fetchDataSpeedtestKel();
    }, [bounds, setIsLoading, tokenArcgis]);

    if (data) {
        return (
            <>
                <GeoJSON
                    ref={geoJsonLayer}
                    data={data}
                />
            </>
        );
    }
}
```

Thank you so much! Jim

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why TypeError: map.addLayer is not a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73024636/why-typeerror-map-addlayer-is-not-a-function)

Comment: That's right, but I'll make it clearer

Answer (score 0):

```
setData(FeatureCollection);
L.heatLayer(points).addTo(position);
setPosition(data);
```

"setData" this update function doesn’t update the value right away.
Rather, it enqueues the update operation. Then, after re-rendering the component, the argument of useState will be ignored and this function will return the most recent value inside data.

May be you can try something like `setPosition(FeatureCollection);`

Comment: Also I see that you have created two similar loops one is forEach and another is map on response.features to populate array and points. You can move both of them under one loop.

Comment: I wanted to ask earlier, I wanted to move both of them under a circle, but I'm confused, is it like this in the [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/12Et13lA66wLpEVnaco8W0Z47BCh3wk4h/view?usp=sharing). And but there are no more errors, only now the heatmap colors don't come out.

Comment: You can try Something like,

'let array = [];
 let points = [];
 response.features.forEach((element) => {
       points.push([
                    element["geometry"]["x"],
                    element["geometry"]["y"]
               ])
       array.push({
             type: "Feature",
              properties: element["attributes"],
              geometry: {
              type: "Point",
              coordinates: [
                    element["geometry"]["x"],
                         element["geometry"]["y"],
                      ],
               },
        });
});'

Comment: For colors I think there is not enough info here for me to comment. I think you should ask/create a new question for colors.

Comment: I created a new question for heatmap color in maps: [link : 'TypeError: map is undefined'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73063032/typeerror-map-is-undefined)